# iOS: Find url in string and change the string to be clickable (tapable)

Tags: ios, iphone

I have a string (for example: "This is some text with specific http://goo.gl/45hz web adress in it").
I need to find all URLs within the string if any and then convert somehow the string so the address will be tapable (safari will open if user taps on it) and i need to display the whole string with URL in label idealy (if possible).

Does anybody know how can be this achieved?

Answer (score 2):

In order to find all URLS in a string

```
NSError *error = NULL;

NSString *string = @"This is some text with specific http://goo.gl/45hz web adress in it";
NSDataDetector *detector = [NSDataDetector dataDetectorWithTypes:NSTextCheckingTypeLink error:&error];
NSArray *matches = [detector matchesInString:string
                                     options:0
                                       range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])];
for (NSTextCheckingResult *match in matches) {
    if ([match resultType] == NSTextCheckingTypeLink) {
        NSURL *url = [match URL];
        NSLog(@"url...%@", url);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `NSRange`  to find the `http://` first and and from that location, discard the text before `http://`, finally  you can separate the remaining string using spaces, take first part of the remaining string which will contain URL.

```
NSString *givenStr = @"This is some text with specific http://goo.gl/45hz web address in it";
NSRange range = [givenStr rangeOfString:@"http://" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];


if (range.location != NSNotFound) {

  NSString *urlString = [givenStr substringFromIndex:range.location]; 
   // urlString="http://goo.gl/45hz web address in it"

  NSArray *urlStrArray = [urlString componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];

  NSURL *finalURL=[NSURL URLWithString:[urlStrArray objectAtIndex:0]];
   // [urlStrArray objectAtIndex:0]="http://goog.gl/45hz"
}
```

For making URL clickable as said by @calampunay you should use `UITextView` instead of `UILabel` because `UILabel` presents only plain text.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `UITextView` instead of `UILabel`. Set `editable` to `NO` and then modify the property `@property(nonatomic) UIDataDetectorTypes dataDetectorTypes` to detect URLs.

Answer (score 1):

**#In swift 5 you will try like this way to find URL**

```
let input = "here is your String"
let detector = try! NSDataDetector(types: NSTextCheckingResult.CheckingType.link.rawValue)
let matches = detector.matches(in: input, options: [], range:NSRange(location: 0, length: input.utf16.count))

for match in matches {
guard let range = Range(match.range, in: input) else { continue }
let url = input[range]
print(url)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use TTTAttributedLabel if this is coming from a UI label - https://github.com/mattt/TTTAttributedLabel

Works great for us.

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented same feature in swift 3. Below is the complete code to detect url in string and make it tapable :

```
//put these lines of code inside your function
//add Tap Gesture
    let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapLabel))
    myLabel?.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)

    let input = “tap on url http://www.google.com, to go to google search”
    myLabel?.attributedText = getAttributedString(input: input);


/*** functions to perform complete task ***/

//function to get attributed string with url
func getAttributedString(input : String) -> NSMutableAttributedString {

    let matches = getURLRange(input: input)
    let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string:input)

    for match in matches {
        let url = (input as NSString).substring(with: match.range)
        print(url)

        let linkText = NSMutableAttributedString(string:url, attributes:[NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.blue] as [String : Any])
        attributedString.replaceCharacters(in: match.range, with: linkText)
    }

    return attributedString
}


//function to get urls range
func getURLRange(input : String) -> [NSTextCheckingResult] {

    let detector = try! NSDataDetector(types: NSTextCheckingResult.CheckingType.link.rawValue)
    let matches = detector.matches(in: input, options: [], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: input.utf16.count))

    return matches
}


// function to check if URL is taped
func tapLabel(gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

    let matches = getURLRange(input: (myLabel?.text)!)

    let tapLocation = gesture.location(in: myLabel)


    let indexOfCharacter = didTapAttributedTextInLabel(label: myLabel!, tapLocation: tapLocation)

    for match in matches {

        if NSLocationInRange(indexOfCharacter, match.range) {

            //open selected URL
            let mainText = myLabel?.text as NSString?
            let urlToOpen = URL(string: (mainText?.substring(with: match.range))!)
            UIApplication.shared.open(urlToOpen!)
            break;
        }else {
            print("Tapped none")
        }

    }

}

//function to get index Of selected Character in string
func didTapAttributedTextInLabel(label: UILabel, tapLocation: CGPoint) -> Int  {


    //here myLabel is the object of UILabel
    //added this from @warly's answer
    //set font of attributedText
    let attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: myLabel!.attributedText!)
    attributedText.addAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: myLabel!.font], range: NSMakeRange(0, (myLabel!.attributedText?.string.characters.count)!))

    // Create instances of NSLayoutManager, NSTextContainer and NSTextStorage
    let layoutManager = NSLayoutManager()
    let textContainer = NSTextContainer(size: CGSize(width: (myLabel?.frame.width)!, height: (myLabel?.frame.height)!+100))
    let textStorage = NSTextStorage(attributedString: attributedText)

    // Configure layoutManager and textStorage
    layoutManager.addTextContainer(textContainer)
    textStorage.addLayoutManager(layoutManager)

    // Configure textContainer
    textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0.0
    textContainer.lineBreakMode = myLabel!.lineBreakMode
    textContainer.maximumNumberOfLines = myLabel!.numberOfLines
    let labelSize = myLabel!.bounds.size
    textContainer.size = labelSize

    // get the index of character where user tapped
    let indexOfCharacter = layoutManager.characterIndex(for: tapLocation, in: textContainer, fractionOfDistanceBetweenInsertionPoints: nil)

    return indexOfCharacter
}
```

It is tested and working fine inside my app.

Answer (score 0):

Swift 4 implementation of **Ankur's** answer:

```
let messageLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14, weight: UIFont.Weight.regular)
        label.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

        return label
    }()

override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        self.addSubview(messageLabel)
        // setup messageLabel constraints 

        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapLabel))
        messageLabel.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)


    }

//function to get attributed string with url
    func getAttributedString(input : String) -> NSMutableAttributedString {

        let matches = getURLRange(input: input)
        let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string:input)

        for match in matches {
            let url = (input as NSString).substring(with: match.range)

            let linkText = NSMutableAttributedString(string:url, attributes:[NSAttributedString.Key(rawValue: NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor.rawValue) : UIColor.appleBlue()])
            attributedString.replaceCharacters(in: match.range, with: linkText)
        }

        return attributedString
    }

    func getURLRange(input : String) -> [NSTextCheckingResult] {

        let detector = try! NSDataDetector(types: NSTextCheckingResult.CheckingType.link.rawValue)
        let matches = detector.matches(in: input, options: [], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: input.utf16.count))

        return matches
    }

    //function to get index Of selected Character in string
    func didTapAttributedTextInLabel(label: UILabel, tapLocation: CGPoint) -> Int  {


        //here myLabel is the object of UILabel
        //added this from @warly's answer
        //set font of attributedText
        let attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: messageLabel.attributedText!)
        attributedText.addAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.font: messageLabel.font], range: NSMakeRange(0, (messageLabel.attributedText?.string.count)!))

        // Create instances of NSLayoutManager, NSTextContainer and NSTextStorage
        let layoutManager = NSLayoutManager()
        let textContainer = NSTextContainer(size: CGSize(width: messageLabel.frame.width, height: messageLabel.frame.height+100))
        let textStorage = NSTextStorage(attributedString: attributedText)

        // Configure layoutManager and textStorage
        layoutManager.addTextContainer(textContainer)
        textStorage.addLayoutManager(layoutManager)

        // Configure textContainer
        textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0.0
        textContainer.lineBreakMode = messageLabel.lineBreakMode
        textContainer.maximumNumberOfLines = messageLabel.numberOfLines
        let labelSize = messageLabel.bounds.size
        textContainer.size = labelSize

        // get the index of character where user tapped
        let indexOfCharacter = layoutManager.characterIndex(for: tapLocation, in: textContainer, fractionOfDistanceBetweenInsertionPoints: nil)

        return indexOfCharacter
    }


    // function to check if URL is taped
    @objc func tapLabel(gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

        let matches = getURLRange(input: (messageLabel.text)!)

        let tapLocation = gesture.location(in: messageLabel)


        let indexOfCharacter = didTapAttributedTextInLabel(label: messageLabel, tapLocation: tapLocation)

        for match in matches {

            if NSLocationInRange(indexOfCharacter, match.range) {

                //open selected URL
                let mainText = messageLabel.text as NSString?
                if let urlToOpen = URL(string: (mainText?.substring(with: match.range))!) {
                    UIApplication.shared.open(urlToOpen)
                } else {
                    print("We have error with URL")
                }
                break
            } else {
                print("Tapped none")
            }

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 5** extension

```
extension String {
    func extractUrl() -> URL? {
        let detector = try! NSDataDetector(types: NSTextCheckingResult.CheckingType.link.rawValue)
        let matches = detector.matches(in: self, options: [], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: self.utf16.count))

        for match in matches {
            guard let range = Range(match.range, in: self) else { continue }
            let url = self[range]
            return URL(string: String(url))
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```